# Select the quickest laptime of a driver per track

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a problem with a query for mysql.

I have 2 tables:

```
tijden
kartbaan
```

in the `tijden` are all the laptimes stored. I store: `tijdenId`, `rijderId`, `baan`, `datum`, `tijd`. 
in the `kartbaan` is the data store about a track.

What I need is the quickest laptime of a driver per track.

```
$sqlTijden = "SELECT *
FROM tijden, kartbaan
WHERE tijden.rijder = '".$_GET['profiel']."' && kartbaan.kartbaanId = tijden.baan
GROUP BY kartbaan.kartbaanId
ORDER BY  tijden.tijd ASC";
```

That is what I do. What happens now is that I get just one laptime per track. But not the quickest. But it is getting the first time of that track. How do I get the quickest?

Comment: This query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, it might help if you used English field names (at least for this example)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT kartbaan.kartbaanId, MIN(tijden.tijd)
FROM tijden JOIN kartbaan
ON kartbaan.kartbaanId = tijden.baan
WHERE tijden.rijder = '".$_GET['profiel']."' -- Please escape this.
GROUP BY kartbaan.kartbaanId
ORDER BY  tijden.tijd ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified version by using curly brackets to avoid escape characters confusion:

**Avoid SQK Injection**:

```
$profile = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['profiel']);


SELECT kartbaan.kartbaanId, MIN(tijden.tijd)
FROM tijden 
JOIN kartbaan
ON kartbaan.kartbaanId = tijden.baan
WHERE tijden.rijder = '{$profile}'
GROUP BY kartbaan.kartbaanId
ORDER BY  tijden.tijd ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Select min(laptime) will probably work